# Height of content loaded in UIWebViewController

Tags: pdf, ios4, uiwebview, height

I am trying to calculate the height of PDF files dynamically loaded in UIWebView. This is because I need to change pages pragmatically. In iOS 5 i found it an easy task. I can simply get the height from the scrollview property

```
pageHeight = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height / numberOfPages;
```

and switching pages is also easy

```
[[webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,y) animated:YES];
```

But versions below iOS 5 UIWebViewController don't provide a scrollView property. Can anyone help me in finding the height and switching pages in versions below iOS 4.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think evaluating JavaScript would work in your case.

What I ended up doing in project was sub-classing UIWebView and implementing the scrollView property myself. So if in iOS5, I return `[super scrollView]`, otherwise I iterate over the subviews until I find the scrollview:

```
for (id subview in webView.subviews)
  if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
    return subview;
```

This way you can share code between iOS 4 and 5.

Comment: Leo, Thanks for your kind response. I ran a test case with above code and seems like its gonna work for me. Thumbs up. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, enjoy.

Comment: Leo, i appreciate your kind response. This solution is working perfectly except i can't zoom in/out the webView in iOS 4. Even scalesPageToFix property set with value true. Any thoughts ? Thanks again for your response. it helped me a lot.

Comment: Did you perhaps change the delegate of the scrollView? In iOS 4 that will not work (I have a workaround for that as well if you need it).
But changing the contentOffset property should not introduce such problems.

Comment: Yes you're right i am playing with its delegate. I need to perform some calculations in didScroll and didZoom. I shall be very thankful if you help me in this issue too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a new question and I will post an example class. Link to the question here.

Comment: I am thankful for your help. I have posted a new question on link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698366/cant-zoom-in-out-scrollview-of-a-class-which-is-subclassed-from-webview[link]

Comment: `[[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]` should be written as `[subview isKindOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]`